# Formula for calculating volume discount for bulk product purchases

Tags: exponential-function, harmonic-functions

I'm trying to work out a basic formula for calculating a volume discount for volume product purchasing (i.e: the per-unit price decreases more and more as the number of units purchased increases). The simple way to go is to set pricing tiers (i.e: `<100 = $40.00 per unit, 100-199 = $30.00 per unit, 200-299 = $25.00 per unit etc.`), but if this were to be plotted on a graph displaying per-unit prices as the number of units purchased increased, it would show a stepped trend, i.e:

[image]

Therefore, a similar graph showing total cost as the number of units purchased would also show a stepped trend.

I was hoping there is a formula I can use that dispenses with the lazy tiering method, and can provide a smooth trend at a per-unit resolution, suiting the below example:

[image]

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the "lazy tiering method?"

Comment: Try $C/n$ for some $C$ you choose.

Comment: @saulspatz "The simple way to go is to set pricing tiers (i.e: `<100 = $40.00 per unit, 100-199 = $30.00 per unit, 200-299 = $25.00 per unit etc.`)"

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use the `X` to the `Y` power function on the calculator and use a decimal for the power, `.95` or something like that to represent the discount for volume discounts. For example `$40` to the `.95` power. `X` would be the number of units they are purchasing and the `$40` is your starting price and the `.95` power would do the discounting (cheaper per unit the more you buy). Apologize for the autoformatting I can't seem to fix it so I included a written equation in the link.

Click on the link to view the equation written out

[x($40) to the .95power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrn55.png)